# get data from multiple csv file and print Highest, Lowest day weather with Humid from any year and also print month name and day in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, extract

[image: csv file as a sample]
Hi everyone. I have multiple CSV files I am creating a weatherman app in python. I am getting data from CSV files and here is the code

```
import os
import csv


lst_temp = []
lst_hum = []
dates = []


class Weather:
    def main(self):
        path = r'C:\Users\someone\PycharmProjects\untitled\weatherfiles\\'
        os.system('cls')
        for files in os.listdir(path):
            if files.endswith('.txt'):
                with open(path + files, 'r') as weather:
                    input_file = csv.reader(weather)
                    for row in input_file:
                        date = row[0].split('-')
                        if date[0] == '2013':
                            lst_temp.append(row[1])
                            lst_hum.append(row[7])
                            lst_temp_int = [int(i) for i in lst_temp if i]
                            lst_hum_int = [int(i) for i in lst_hum if i]
                            sorted_lst = sorted(lst_temp_int)
                            sorted_hum_lst = sorted(lst_hum_int)
        
        print(f"Highest: {sorted_lst[-1]}C")
        print(f"Lowest: {sorted_lst[0]}C")
        print(f"Humid: {sorted_hum_lst[-1]}%")
```

they are giving me data in this format

```
Highest: 70C
Lowest: -1C
Humid: 100%
```

I need the result in this format

```
Highest: 45C on June 23
Lowest: 01C on December 22
Humid: 95% on August 14
```

can anyone help me I am very grateful for this? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import os



temperatures = []
temperatures_min = []

class Weather:
    def Year_Temp(self):
        path = r'C:\Users\someone\PycharmProjects\untitled\weatherfiles\\'
        year = self.func
        os.system('cls')
        for files in os.listdir(path):
            if files.endswith('.txt'):
                with open(path + files, 'r') as weather:
                    input_file = csv.reader(weather)
                    next(input_file)
                    for line in input_file:
                        if year in line[0]:
                            date = line[0]
                            temp_max = line[1]
                            temp_min = line[3]
                            humd = line[8]
                            temperatures.append(temp_max)
                            dates.append(date)
                            temperatures_min.append(temp_min)
                            lst_hum.append(humd)


        res = dict(zip(temperatures, dates))
        new_dict = {k: v for k, v in res.items() if k != ''}
        max_temp = max(new_dict, key=int)
        strpt_date = new_dict.get(max_temp)
        mydate = datetime.strptime(strpt_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
        strf_date = mydate.strftime('%B %d')
        print(f"Highest: {max_temp}C, {strf_date}")

        res_one = dict(zip(temperatures_min, dates))
        new_dict_one = {k: v for k, v in res_one.items() if k != ''}
        min_temp = min(new_dict_one, key=int)
        strpt_date_one = new_dict_one.get(min_temp)
        mydate_one = datetime.strptime(strpt_date_one, '%Y-%m-%d')
        strf_date_one = mydate_one.strftime('%B %d')
        print(f"Lowest: {min_temp}C, {strf_date_one}")

        res_two = dict(zip(lst_hum, dates))
        new_dict_two = {k: v for k, v in res_two.items() if k != ''}
        max_humd = max(new_dict_two, key=int)
        strpt_date_two = new_dict_two.get(max_humd)
        mydate_two = datetime.strptime(strpt_date_two, '%Y-%m-%d')
        strf_date_two = mydate_two.strftime('%B %d')
        print(f"Humid: {max_humd}%, {strf_date_two}")
```

*your Wellcome*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pandas to parse data files.

Assuming the column names are the same throughout your .txt files:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',', parse_dates=['PKT'])
```

After that, you can retrieve the index of the max temperature using .idxmax() like so:

```
max_i = df['Max TemperatureC'].idxmax()
max_temp_row = df.iloc[max_i]
```

Or the minimum temperature using .idxmin()

```
min_i = df['Max TemperatureC'].idxmin()
min_temp_row = df.iloc[max_i]
```

I highly recommend you read the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for more info.

Comment: thank you for your work but I want to do this without pandas.